# Conectar PgAdmin via SSH Google Cloud

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ssh, pgadmin

Boas pessoal, seguinte.
Tenho um server no Google Cloud, e instalei o postgres e tudo ok, está funcionando beleza, ai na minha máquina instalei o pgAdmin III e fiz a configuração para conectar com o banco, inicialmente funcionou, depois parou de funcionar, pois minha internet caiu e meu IP mudou, e tive que fazer uma regra no firewall do google liberando acesso para o meu IP, então vi aqui um problema, pois cada vez que trocar meu IP terei que trocar no firewall..

Pensei em fazer a conexão via SSH, mas não faço ideia como fazer isso, não encontrei tutoriais nem nada..

Alguém tem ideia de como resolver meu problema?

Obrigado

Comment: quem bloqueia é o firewall do servidor, ou o próprio postgresql ? Caso seja o firewall, não tem como liberar uma faixa, ou um domínio ? Como foi a configuração que você fez ?

Comment: o firewall do servidor, as opções são: `Intervalos de IP, SUB-REDES, Tags de Origem`

Comment: Questões de configuração de serviços, aplicações e infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su], [sf], https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ou mesmo no https://dba.stackexchange.com/ conforme o assunto. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que andei lendo na documentação do google cloud, você pode fazer uma liberação no firewall liberando uma range de ips.

apenas para testes, faça a liberação de qualquer ip na porta do postgresql:

```
--network my-network \
--action allow \
--direction ingress \
--rules tcp:5432 \
--source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 \
--priority 50 \
```

Se quiser melhorar a segurança, liberando apenas uma range conhecida, seria melhor, por exemplo, somente a range que pertence ao Brasil.